# Joomla 2.5 : Error 500 : Internal Server Error

Tags: joomla, error-handling, joomla2.5, internal-server-error

I have website already and wanted to do many changes in website. So I took the akeeba backup and created site locally.

When I created website, I got error as `Internal Server Error`. To solve that error I removed whatever was there in .htaccess file. Now website is working locally, however administrator is not working.

I followed the [answer of same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225027/500-internal-server-error-at-back-end-joomla), however it is not working.

***Can anyone point, where I am going wrong? I need this to be done anyhow.***

---

### Edit 1

Below is what I have in `apache_error.log`

```
[Thu Nov 29 10:22:34 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Nov 29 10:22:34 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Nov 29 10:22:34 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 29 10:23:29 2012] [error] [client ::1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /home5/smartkwc/public_html/administrator/.htpasswd
[Thu Nov 29 11:02:33 2012] [error] [client ::1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /home5/smartkwc/public_html/administrator/.htpasswd
[Thu Nov 29 11:03:28 2012] [error] [client ::1] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /home5/smartkwc/public_html/administrator/.htpasswd
```

Comment: have you edited your configuration.php to ensure it coinsides with your localhost? Also, try taking a backup of the site without using Akeeba. I personally always make a zip of the FTP, and backup the database separately.

Comment: @Lodder : Any idea how to work with my situation? My net is so slow and I can't go with option of downloading again

Comment: Hmm ok fair enough. Try renaming htaccess to htaccess.txt ... can you also provide me with a cooy of your configuration.php please?

Comment: @Lodder : I don't have anything in it.... When I make it blank, website started working

Comment: If your site isn't too big and you're willing to do this, you could always install a fresh copy of Joomla, install your template and extensions, then upload the database.

Comment: @Lodder : My site is 455 MB and as internet speed is very low, I can't download it as you said. Hence I want to deal with jpa file that I have.

Comment: Not a lot I can suggest to be honest. Have a look on Google and the Joomla forums to see what other people have said ;)

Comment: Rather than just randomly removing files, have you checked the server log to see what the error message is? That should give you a clue as to what the cause of the problem is.

Comment: @Lodder : can you take a look at my new question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196897/main-link-gives-error-500-while-sublink-works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem!!!

Earlier I had removed content of `.htaccess` from root folder only. Now when I removed everything from `.htaccess` from administrator folder, all is working perfectly. :) :) :)

Yipeee!!!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the contents of .htaccess are a vital part of Joomla's security protocol. The proper solution is to find out which specific line of your .htaccess file is incompatible with your server's configuration and correct it. Often, uncommenting '# RewriteBase /' solves the problem.