# got 500 Internal Server error in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7, joomla1.6

Whenever I try to access my site I got "**500 Internal Server Error**" in front-end as well as in back-end.

**Error:**

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Request Timeout

This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'. 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I also try to resolved this issue by changing the permission of some files but nothing happen.

Please help me I really need it.

Comment: @Rikesh No. my question is different. I face issue front-end side as well back-end side. I am not able to access both.

Comment: And I also try solution which is give in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225027/500-internal-server-error-at-back-end-joomla but nothing happen.

Comment: There can be many problems of this cause. Try to take backup of your .htacess & update with the original one.

Comment: @Rikesh Thanks for your reply. Yes i try to upload joomla's original .htaccess but same result. nothing happen.

Comment: Are you running your site on any server or on local ? You have any sef plugin installed in your site ?

Comment: Yes. My site properly run in local and i check all the files and directory and everything same as local site.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24514/discussion-between-rikesh-and-parag-bhargav)