# Jomsocial shows HTTP error when Uploading photo and shows Error 500 page cannot be found in uploading avatar

Tags: joomla, jomsocial

I m unable to make out...in jomsocial photo upload
I have joomla ver 2.5.9 and jomsocial version 2.8 and server is shared hosting linux and i m using JF Social Template ver 1.3

My prob is when i upload photo in jomsocial its shows HTTP error.. however image upload works fine in joomla articles and k2
Though it upload small image in png format but jpeg shows error. My server has GD lib is enabled on server

Plz help me out , actually it works fine in local host

Thanks
Krisu

Comment: This should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225027/500-internal-server-error-at-back-end-joomla