# Joomla administrator re-directs to homepage in localhost

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, localhost

I am trying to access my localhost version of the Joomla Administrator, however each time I navigate to the administrator directory, my Joomla website index page loads instead?

I suspect the htaccess file may be the issue but not 100%?

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Do you by any chance have a admin protection plugin that re-directs users if they try to access the admin panel? Such as **Admin Exile**?

Comment: I do have on my live site, so there may be a chance that module may be causing the problem.  However because I can't login to localhost admin I can't disable it

Comment: I've logged into my phpadmin and looked in the jos_extensions for the component (jsecure) but its not in the table.  Therefore could it be the htaccess right enough?

Comment: If you have *jsecure* installed on your site, then it **will** be in the `jos_extensions` database table.

Comment: Hi Lodder, appreciate your help.  I don't understand why, but the jsecure extension is not appearing in my phpadmin interface.  However when I view my database in Mac Terminal, sure enough the jsecure appears as a row int he jos_extensions table.  Therefore would I be just as well deleting it?  There's also a System - jsecure row?

Comment: Don't delete it. Do the same process I have shown you in my answer below but do it on your live site. Once, done, take a backup of the database and replace the database on your localhost with the backup you took.

Comment: Ok - progress :)  The Admin login screen now loads.  However I now get an 500 error ?

Comment: This might help with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225027/500-internal-server-error-at-back-end-joomla

Comment: This is the error I get in the error log........open(./logs/error.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mydir/libraries/joomla/log/loggers/formattedtext.php on line 248   and  fputs() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mydir/libraries/joomla/log/loggers/formattedtext.php on line 254

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok seeing as you have some protection plugin which re-directs the user from the admin panel if they try and access the page, you won't be able to to either.

And seeing as you can't login to disable it, you will have to do it manually via PhpMyAdmin. Follow these instructions:

1. Enter PhpMyAdmin
2. Open the table called `jos_extensions` (**jos** is the prefix which may be different for you)
3. Find the protection extension you have installed which is causing the redirect and go to edit it.
4. You will find a column called **enabled**. You need to change the value from **1** to **0**

You should then be able to login to the Joomla admin panel

Hope this helps