# Joomla on MAMP - blank page

Tags: mamp, server-error, joomla3.4

I'm new at this and I'm having a lot of troubles... I tried to installed Joomla 3.4.6 on MAMP 3.2 but, when I open the locahost to do the installation, appears a "server error 500".

What can I do to fix this? I'd really be thankful!

Comment: You need to give more information, in what directory did you place your website ? What did you type in your URL ? etc... Please edit your question

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225027/500-internal-server-error-at-back-end-joomla