# HTTP Error when trying to edit Joomla on localhost

Tags: joomla, mamp, http-error

I made a backup of my live Joomla site using Akeeba and used kickstart to upload the backup to MAMP on Windows. The front-side of the site on localhost displays correctly and I am able to log in to the admin side. But, when I try to edit an article, or initiate updates to Joomla, extensions, etc I get an HTTP Error 500 page displayed. I am new to Joomla so any help you can provide would be appreciated. Let me know what additional info you may need. Thanks!

I tried renaming the .htaccess file to .htaccess.old and a new htaccess file was created, with no effect.

Expected Result: edit an article or update Joomla/extensions
Actual Result: Click on Edit or Update and receive HTTP Error 500

Comment: There is actually a dedicated StackExchange site just for Joomla [joomla.se] and this question will get a  better answer there.

Comment: Thank you, Elin. I will post on the Joomla site.

Answer (score 0):

First check if **/logs and /tmp** directories have a writing permission.

**From Joomla Administrator Backend:**

For editing **/logs** path of Joomla - Go to **Joomla administrator** -> Click on **System** -> **Global Configuration** -> Find **System** tab and edit **Path to Log Folder**, here you need to add site server root path of your /logs directory.

For editing **/tmp** path of Joomla - Go to **Joomla administrator** -> Click on **System** -> **Global Configuration** -> Find **Server** tab and edit **Path to Temp Folder**, here you need to add site server root path of your /tmp directory

**From Joomla Configuration file:**

Follow this post for editing **/logs and /tmp** directories  - [500 internal server error at back end - Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225027/500-internal-server-error-at-back-end-joomla)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Here are the paths I currently have for the log and tmp directories and I am still encountering an issue.  

C:/MAMP/htdocs/logs (Updated just now from /home/radu/public_html/logs)
C:/MAMP/htdocs/tmp

Comment: After re-reading the article linked I updated the log and tmp directories to './logs' and './tmp' and I thought I had it working for a moment and then it went back to the same issue.

I did just notice this warning message within Joomla Admin that I am not sure if it was there previously: 
Warning
Error loading component: com_fields, Component not found.

Comment: @stephanie which version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: I was able to fix the error loading component warning. I'm on Joomla! 3.7.5. The site I'm uploading from akeeba backup is on PHP 5.5.32 and my localhost through MAMP is on PHP 7.2.10 - could this cause this type of error message?